# is anyone seeing CORS problems on MS QnA maker?

Tags: azure-qna-maker, azure-language-understanding

each time i try to `save and train` on Luis.ai I just get an error dialog and

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://puzzleqna.cognitiveservices.azure.com/qnamaker/v4.0/knowledgebases/.....
from origin 'https://www.qnamaker.ai' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response. 
6.fe97106b3db0546c50…olyfills.chunk.js:2 
PATCH https://puzzleqna.cognitiveservices.azure.com/qnamaker/v4.0/knowledgebases/xxx... net::ERR_FAILED
```

have had this problem over a couple of days so I imagine it's something related to my account but not sure.

Comment: what is the luis portal link that you are using? Is it luis.ai or eu.luis.ai or au.luis.ai? Also, could you please check if the app service of your QnAMaker resource has any CORS restrictions in it properties?

Comment: no it was a new account i setup. Additionally I'm getting billed $$$/day for the basic Azure four or five services it seems to need to even get started with QnA maker. Terrible experience. Back to dialogflow with all its warts or RASA I guess.